# How can I safely handle invalid requests for repository data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, repository, asp.net-web-api-routing

With this code:

```
public String Get(int id)
{
        return platypi.Find(p => p.Id == id).Name;
}
```

...I can get existing data via:

```
http://localhost:33181/api/DPlatypus/N
```

(where N corresponds to an existing ID). If I use a nonexistent value, though, it blows up.

So, I tried this:

```
public String Get(int id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(platypi.Find(p => p.Id == id).Name))
    {
        return platypi.Find(p => p.Id == id).Name;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

...but it has no beneficial effect. Is there a way to safely ignore invalid requests?

Comment: "it blows up" doesn't provide enough details to completely help you out...

Comment: Does it "blow up" on the find? or on the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be much more defensive than that. Check for `null` first.. otherwise you're asking for it to blow up:

```
var entity = platypi.Find(p => p.Id == id);

return entity == null ? string.Empty : entity.Name;
```

You're also currently doing more than a single lookup.. which you don't need (`Find` to check name.. then `Find` to return name..).

Answer (score 3):

If the `Find` method is raising an exception, you could wrap this in an exception handler.  That would allow you to "safely" return an empty string on invalid input.

If `Find` returns `null`, you could do:

```
public String Get(int id)
{
    var item = platypi.Find(p => p.Id == id);

    return item == null ? string.Empty : item.Name;
}
```