# Why am I getting an InvalidCastException with competing Newtonshoft.Json.Linq.[JArray,JObject] with very similar code/data?

Tags: rest, httpwebrequest, json.net, streamreader, httpwebresponse

This code works fine - returns the single record that matches the REST query:

```
Popul8TheGrid("http://localhost:28642/api/subdepartments/1/10");

private void Popul8TheGrid(string URIToPass)
{
    try
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetRESTData(URIToPass);
    }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Eek, a mousey-pooh! ({0})", webex.Message);
    }
}

private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
}
```

However, this code, which also should return a single record:

```
private const string BASE_URI = "http://localhost:28642/api/";
. . .
string URIToPass = string.Format("{0}deliveryitems/{1}", BASE_URI, numericUpDownDeliveryItemId.Value);
Popul8TheGrid(URIToPass);
```

...fails, with "*InvalidCastException was unhandled ...  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'*".

Why might that be? The data returned from the first (working) snippet comes from an MS Access "database"

The data from the second (failing) snippet is from test data:

```
public DeliveryItemRepository() 
{
    // Just some bogus/test data for now
    Add(new DeliveryItem
    {
        Id = 1, InvoiceNumber = "123", UPC_PLU = "456", VendorItemId = "789", PackSize = 1, Description = "Something", Quantity = 5, Cost = 1.25M, 
        Margin = 0.25M, ListPrice = 1.50M, DepartmentNumber = 42, Subdepartment = "5"
    });
```

. . .

This is the Controller method; it works fine when entering the URI in a browser.

```
// Enter "http://localhost:28642/api/1"
[Route("api/DeliveryItems/{ID:int}")] 
public DeliveryItem GetDeliveryItemById(int ID)
{
    return _deliveryItemRepository.GetById(ID);
}
```

...but why that would matter, I know not...

### UPDATE

Interestingly enough (perhaps I'm easily amused), this, OTOH, works:

```
MessageBox.Show(GetRESTScalarVal("http://localhost:28642/api/deliveries/1"));
. . .
private string GetRESTScalarVal(string uri)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

By "works," I mean it returns this:

[image]

So DownloadString() will even return an entire json "record" and my use of the word "Scalar" was misleading. Maybe I should have said "Single" instead, although that can be confusing, too, what with the data type of the same appellation.

The question still remains as to how I can populate a datagrid with a single json "record"

## UPDATE 2

Oddly enough, if I use a different Controller method to get the one record, it works:

```
private void GetDeliveryItemById()
{
    //string uri = string.Format("deliveryitems/{0}", numericUpDownId.Value);
    string uri = string.Format("deliveryitems/{0}/1", numericUpDownId.Value);
    Popul8TheGrid(uri);
}
```

The commented out code is what blows up, whereas the other, with a provided const val of 1, works...kludgy, but it works.

### UPDATE 3

Perhaps a clue/related to why it won't work when fetching one, but works otherwise, is this Repository code:

```
public SiteMapping GetById(int ID)
{
    return siteMappings.Find(p => p.Id == ID);
}

public IEnumerable<SiteMapping> GetRange(int ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return siteMappings.Where(i => i.Id >= ID).Take(CountToFetch);
}
```

If GetById() is called with an ID that exists, it works; if one is passed that doesn't exist, though, it fails with, "InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code . . .  Message=Sequence contains no matching element"

Calling GetRange() works robustly - if passed a bogus pair of vals (no records), it simply shrugs its shoulders, rather than getting the old bulgy eye and screaming maniacally.

Changing it to so (see Simon Whitehead's answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125722/how-can-i-safely-handle-invalid-requests-for-repository-data)) works:

```
public SiteMapping GetById(int ID)
{
    var entity = siteMappings.Find(p => p.Id == ID);
    return entity == null ? null : entity;
}
```

So trying to find by a particular ID is fragile; trying to find by ID + Count works just fine. Why, I (still) don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be somewhat kludgy, but it works:

```
private JArray GetRESTData(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
    }
    catch // This method crashes if only one json "record" is found - try this:
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(GetScalarVal(uri));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private string GetScalarVal(string uri)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    return client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```